# Find invalid bz2 file preferable using C/C++

Tags: c, bz2

I have around 200 thousand bz2 files in which only one 1 valid. The size of each bz2 file is less than 200 bytes. I need to find the valid one. The command line bz2 utility is taking too much time.

Is there minimal check using file bytes by which I can find invalid bz2 and ignore further processing. I want to do in C/C++ as it would be way faster than shell scripts.

Comment: C and C++ are distinct languages.  There is no "C/C++".  In any event, how do you imagine the command-line utility you're already using is implemented?  In either C or C++, almost certainly.  It is unlikely that the shell is adding much overhead.  It is possible that a special-purpose tool would be somewhat more efficient, but unless yours is a frequently recurring task, the time and effort to develop such a tool is unlikely to be justified by the time saved running it.

Comment: There is an informal bzip spec here: https://github.com/dsnet/compress/blob/master/doc/bzip2-format.pdf

Comment: "Minimal check" is not a reliable check. It can exclude files that are not bz2, but not detect if the files are *valid* bz2 files. That said, it would not be that much work to use a thread pool (for files to be checked), and [libbz2](ftp://sources.redhat.com/pub/bzip2/docs/manual_toc.html) to verify each file. It would be basically the same as running `bunzip2 -qt` and checking if its exit status is zero, but without the overhead of executing a separate process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the solution. As per bz2 format, first 3 characters should be 'BZh'. This filtered out all but 19 files.